# Using a simple GUI to run a Cucumber Feature File

Tags: ruby, cucumber, shoes, feature-file

I am utilizing the "shoes" tool to create a window with a button in the middle.  I would like the user to be able click the button and then the program runs a Cucumber feature file, but I don't know how to run a feature file from within a class or if its possible.  Very new at this so any advice is appreciated. Let me know if more information is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
Shoes.app do
  @s = stack {}

  button "Run Cucumber" do
    @out = `cucumber`
    @s.clear { para @out }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the cucumber documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Running-Features) you just run it as any other rake task from within your app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "--format pretty" # Any valid command line option can go here.
end
```

you then just need to put it into a [shoes window](http://shoesrb.com/walkthrough.html) like so:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'
require 'shoes'

Shoes.app {
  @push = button "Run Features"
  @note = para "Haven't run features"
  @push.click {
    result = Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
      t.cucumber_opts = "--format pretty" # Any valid command line option can go here.
    end
    @note.replace result
  }
}
```

or something like that, I haven't actually tested this but look at the outputs and read the documentation and you'll be fine.